# VB.NET Need explanation for Excel.Application

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am very confused as to how Excel.Application works.

Suppose I have the following code:

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWbs As Excel.Workbooks
Dim xlWb As Excel.Workbook

xlWbs = xlApp.Workbooks
xlWb = xlWbs.Open("C:\Users\OPA\Desktop\Outage Macro Project Folder\Customized Outage Macro for Testing.xlsm") 'consider this to be wb1

xlApp.visible = true

xlApp.Run(A macro that creates another workbook wb2) 'this creates another workbook wb2
```

Why is it when I then write:

```
xlApp.Quit()
```

Both Wb1 and Wb2 are terminated? But I did not explicitly set up a reference between Wb2 and xlApp! How did xlApp become the parent of Wb2??

How can I set up an excel reference that explicitly refer to Wb2 after it is created? (i.e. xlNewWb = xlApp.workbooks(wb2) 'this doesn't work) so that when I say xlApp.quit(), wb2 do not cease to exist?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *How did xlApp become the parent of Wb2??*

This line:

```
xlApp.Run(A macro that creates another workbook wb2)
```

executed the macro *in the context of `xlApp`*.

> *How can I set up an excel reference that explicitly refer to Wb2 after it is created, [...] so that when I say xlApp.quit(), wb2 do not cease to exist?*

Create a second instance of `Excel.Application` and execute your macro there.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Could you clarify what you meant by creating a second instance and executing the macro there? The macro is associated with Wb1 (in VBA), so I have to execute it using xlApp.

Comment: If you create Wb2 by executing a macro in Wb1, then Wb1 and Wb2 run in the same Excel instance. You won't be able to change that. You can *close* Wb1 (instead of xlApp), does that help? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi, I want to be able to make another workbook instance to refer to Wb2, is this possible? i.e. xlNewWb = XlApp.wb2 something like that

Comment: If not, how can I refer to Wb2 through xlApp? xlApp.Windows(Wb2.name) doesn't seem to work

Comment: Since Wb2 was started in the xlApp instance, it should be a member of xlApp's Workbooks collection. Have you tried iterating (i.e. `For Each`) through the entires in `xlApp.Workbooks` to see if it is there?